# How can I identify apps that trigger events in MacroDroid

Tags: macrodroid

MacroDroid can be triggered for a broad set of events. In particular it can detect and log when GPS location is enabled or disabled. This is useful but I would like to understand which app made the request.

I would like to find a way to identify the app that made the request associated with the event i.e. which app is requesting GPS location be turned on. Does MacroDroid have the capability to identify the app triggering the event? Alternatively if this is not possible could MacroDroid capture the app that were running at the time GPS location was enabled?

For completeness phone is a Galaxy Note 8 (SM-N950F) running Android 8.0.0

Comment: If the app that is triggering GPS change is in foreground, you could add `[fg_app_name]:[fg_app_package]` to the event and have an notification display that as well. I am not sure but I think an app needs to be in foreground to trigger location change

Comment: You can add those by tapping action and use configure option to select those and any other parameters like time etc from the blue box with dots on right

Comment: Re : the first comment. I don't think *apps* by themselves can switch on or off the GPS. Such apps like MacroDroid need system permissions. It's most likely in your case (guessing) that your OS is triggering and in which case the event log should show *system*

Comment: @beeshyams I'll keep an eye on this over the next few days to see what happens. The reason I am trying to get to the bottom of this is the GPS is being switched on without my explicit consent (that I know of). Additionally in some cases GPS is toggled on and off immediately so it wouldn't be noticeable if one wasn't capturing events. I am trying to find out why this is.

Comment: Cool. If my guess is right you will see this in event or something similar having *system* in it - `System UI:com.android.systemui`.  If that is the case and you are satisfied, please self answer and flag my comments for deletions. Thank you